# Width and height of imageview when loading images from sdcard

Tags: android

I am loading images from sdcard in the imageview. Right now I have set the width and height to wrap_content. How should I set my imageview width and height so the image doesn't looks stretched. There are some images which are also really small when loaded in the imageview if I let the width and height to be wrap_content. What would be the right approach to this?.Thanks

Comment: You should read about SCALE_TYPE

Comment: Basically it depends on your images format, do you mind if they have not the same shape? must they be all of the same size?

Comment: centerCrop/centerInside and maybe adjustViewBounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

in your imageview and try giving fix height and width.